# Jar from library project not resolved in Android app

Tags: android, adt

I'm building an Android app which uses a library that is defined in another Eclipse project (same workspace). All is working fine, but now I added a jar file to the library project's build path. In Eclipse I exported the jar file to make it visible to dependent projects of the library (Build Path -> Order and Export -> mark the jar file). Still Eclipse (ADT) complains that the import cannot be resolved.
I have set up a test project for the library as well, and there the imports are visible after exporting the jar file as mentioned above. 
Is there anything I forgot to configure?

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ADT doesn't seem to pick it up automatically :-/

Manually configuring the main project's build path to rely on the library project's jars worked for me.

Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs -> {Library Project}\libs\myjar.jar

Comment: Keep in mind that not all JAR files will work correctly in Android. If your external JAR has any type of UI stuff in it (ex. swing) -- its probably not going to compile correctly

Comment: if the problem still exists, then probably you have to clean your main project and clean all library projects included in your main project.