# no class def error android studio

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I run application and suddenly getting this error. Although all files are included in my project still its giving me the following error.

Error Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12.fragments.TutorialFragment
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12.adapters.TutorialPagerAdapter.<init>(TutorialPagerAdapter.java:52)
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12.classes.TutorialActivity.onCreate(TutorialActivity.java:55)
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5117)
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
11-13 10:08:34.270 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 10:08:38.134 8938-8938/com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8938 SIG: 9
```

I already tried these links [NoClassDefFoundError for .jar library at runtime in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283688/noclassdeffounderror-for-jar-library-at-runtime-in-android-studio)

[Also this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698287/noclassdeffounderror-with-android-studio-on-android-4)

My Default config code snippet is as follows:

```
 defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12"
                minSdkVersion 14
                targetSdkVersion 23
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                multiDexEnabled true

            }    

    dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
            compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
            compile 'com.squareup.mimecraft:mimecraft:1.1.1'
            compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
            compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
            compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
        }
```

Comment: Make sure that you have TutorialFragment in com.TCYonline.android.TCY_K12.fragments package

Comment: That file is there in that project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in the application tag in your manifest file and this will solve the problem

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```