# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: when referencing jar of custom module. JAVA

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have 2 custom module and an App

Module A
Module B
app

In Main Project, `Module B` is imported as a direct project(no jar/aar).

> build.gradle of **Module B**

```
dependancy{
   implementation project(":Module A")
}
```

> build.gradle of **App**

```
dependancy{
   implementation project(":Module B")
}
```

So it is working fine.

But the problem is when I take a **jar/aar** of **Module B**, and I included in **App**, Then in runtime, I got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` in every class that referred the **Module A** classes.

> So how to fix this?

Comment: Try the solution of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283688/noclassdeffounderror-for-jar-library-at-runtime-in-android-studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: @M.leRutte Yes possible duplicate of question, But I didn't get the solution from there

Comment: @KapilRajput No. It is not the issue of multidex