# Connection code not working for api level lower than 11 - doInBackground crash

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-get

Okay, I have a code that used to work just fine and right now it doesn't work only for devices, lower than 11.
Everything starts out fine and in my main activity I launch an `AsyncTask`, inside `doInBackground` appears the error as shown below:

```
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        final String info = getString(R.string.inf);
        final String post = getString(R.string.pos);
        final String main = getString(R.string.mai);

        String val1 = "";
        String val2 = "";
        String val3 = "";

        int connSucc = 3;

            try {
                JSONTokener sbTokener = new JSONTokener(Sources.httpGet(infoUrlStr).toString()); //==========>>It crashes right here

                JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(sbTokener);
                for(int i=0; i<(jArray.length()); i++)
            {
                JSONObject json_obj_inf = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
             .
             .
             .
```

So I checked `Sources.httpGet`:

```
public static StringBuilder httpGet (String urlStr) {
    StringBuilder err = new StringBuilder();
    hata.append("Error!");

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    BufferedReader rd = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(6000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        if (conn.getResponseCode() >= 200 && conn.getResponseCode() <= 299) {
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();

            conn.disconnect();

        }
        else {
            return err;
        }
    }
    catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException a) {
        return err;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return err;
    }
    finally {
        if (rd != null) {
            try {
                rd.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return err;
            }
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return sb;
}
```

I think it can't even get to this `httpGet` method. As I've said this works just fine for api level higher than 11. Below is my logcat which didn't help me that much.

```
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com.akilli.ticaret.source.Sources
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.akilli.ticaret.Main$RestRequ.doInBackground(Main.java:130)
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.akilli.ticaret.Main$RestRequ.doInBackground(Main.java:1)
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-20 10:32:11.194: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  ... 4 more
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357): Activity com.akilli.ticaret.Main has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45fa6e78 that was originally added here
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.akilli.ticaret.Main has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45fa6e78 that was originally added here
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at com.akilli.ticaret.Main$RestRequ.onPreExecute(Main.java:111)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at com.akilli.ticaret.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:50)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-20 10:32:13.064: E/WindowManager(357):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'd really appreciate the help, I probable made a rookie mistake, and the reason it says that a window is leaked is probably because it crashes before it's even able to dismiss the dialogbox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A code that used to work works no more for api level lower than 11 - crash doInBackground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700379/a-code-that-used-to-work-works-no-more-for-api-level-lower-than-11-crash-doinb)

Comment: @laalto is ther a way for me to 'know' that a code no longer works for api leve lower than 11? how do I keep up and not make a big mess?

Comment: Android Lint generally does a good job of giving warnings about things that are not available in your minSdkLevel. So, pay attention to warnings and run full project lint regularly.

Comment: @laalto right, will do and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using some library that doesn't support Android < API 11

In the future, search stackoverflow for your Java Exception. 
[Getting "Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247862/getting-caused-by-java-lang-verifyerror)

Comment: I am using android-support-v7-appcompat and/or v4, and actually I am using no library for this block of code

Comment: but my libraries are properly in order :